# "is unavailable" error for elements in viewController file

Tags: objective-c

In my new quest to learn objective c, I have can't get past the error in my viewController that a button (which I have declared in the header file - `IBOutlet`) `is unavailable`.

in the header.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MessageContactViewController : TTTemplateViewController
{
    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *showBtn;
    __weak IBOutlet UIView *photoView;
}
@end
```

code in .m file

```
import "header.h"
@implementation MessageContactViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (IS_IOS_7) {
        [showBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_GOTHAM_BOOK size:17]]; // this gives the error: "showBtn" is unavailable
    //some extra code for labels and button

}
```

Please help me out in this and forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

not only IBOUTLET you also give connection in xib then check (OR)

`UIbutton *imgBtn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:sometag];` //give tag in xib

Answer (score 0):

please edit your line with below and try...

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton * showBtn;
```

pls ensure: you had check Target Membership for .m file

[image]

Comment: @Stephen Nyamweya i updated my answer ensure the Target Membership and then clean,build and run again

Comment: I tried the solution about. The target membership is checked but on editing the line as you suggest above gives me the errors: `Type name requires a specifier or qualifier`, `Illegal visibility specification`, `A parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition`.